Emitter Follower - Normal BJT vs Phototransistor
Here is the circuit of normal BJT in emitter follower configuration.

I understand that when conducting, $$V_e = V_b - 0.7$$
In the above case, \$V_e = 1.33V\$
Now, consider an opto coupler circuit as shown below:
( Simulated in SPICE )

The following are the plotted waveforms:

Plot01 -> Diode Current, If
Plot02 -> Collector Current, Ic
Plot03 -> Output at emitter, Vout & Collector voltage(green), 5V
Now the question is, incase of optocoupler circuit, why the emitter voltage is pulled to collector voltage(with some drop from 5V, as shown in the plot03) when the transistor is conducting while in a normal BJT circuit, it is just 0.7V less than Vb?
Am I getting anything wrong here?
Edit : Base voltage vs Emitter voltage added


Why not plot the voltage on the opto-transistor base <-- the terminal is there to be used.

I see you've added a diagram but, it's not clear what that diagram is of and, it's not clear whether you've added it following my previous comment. If it is Vb then, you should plot it on the same graph as Ve using a vertical scale that is common to both.

I am trying to add the plot post your comment

I didn't say you needed to add it; just make comparisons between Vb and Ve

I have added the plot anyway. Thought it can be helpful:)

Does that graph answer your question now @theja

The base voltage is higher than 5V?

The important thing is that it's still an emitter follower.

What do you suppose Vb is, in a phototransistor?

In a phototransistor,  light falling on the base region generates electron-hole pairs which control current flowing through the transistor just like B-E voltage would do in a standard transistor.
In other words, incident light acts upon a phototransistor just as base current acts in a normal transistor. You can think of it as a light-controlled current source connected to the base.

If a standard transistor receives a constant base current Ib, and it has enough Vce to remain in the linear region (not saturated) its output collector current will be  Ib times hFE, in this cay it acts as a current controlled current source. The same thing occurs in an optocoupler: the LED converts current to a proportional flux of photons, which acts like a base current, and the transistor outputs current proportional to it. So, when the transistor is not saturated, an optocoupler acts as a current controlled current source, according to its Current Transfer Ratio (specified in datasheet).
When the transistor is saturated, output current is no longer proportional to input current, instead it is decided by external components, for example R4 in your circuit.
So, in your first circuit, in order to saturate the transistor, you'd need V2 to be about 0.6V above V3. In the opto coupler case, the phototransistor can be saturated if it receives enough light without needing an extra power supply.

Can an emitter follower be saturated?

If the base is brought to a higher voltage than the collector, yes.

In the opto coupler case, the phototransistor can be saturated if it receives enough light without needing an extra power supply - Could you explain this ? How increased light decreases Vce to drive it into saturation?

Light acts as base current, so more light means increased current from collector to emitter. Since you're using it with resistor R4, more current means voltage drop on R4 increases until Vce gets squeezed between R4 and the power supply. Then the transistor is saturated. But if you don't add R4 (or it is very low value) then with more light, the transistor will just conduct more current and will not saturate. Vce is not decided by the transistor, but by what the whole circuit does.

I have understood your explanation. But I still do not have full clarity of the concept.
Here is the thing: let’s say I am operating both the circuits ( Bjt & Opto) in saturation mode. Neglect the values of the circuit above. Now, what will be Value of Vout ? Wheather it is vb-0.7 Or it is pulled to the collector voltage? And what will happen in the linear mode of operation?

In saturation Vce is very low, so Vout is pulled almost to V4 in your opto schematic. In linear mode the opto acts as a controlled current source.

You can saturate the BJT in an emitter follower by raising base potential above the collector, and in that way you can get close to 5V at the emitter, just like the phototransistor.
In a "wired" emitter follower, the energy required to produce the conditions necessary for conduction from collector to emitter comes from \$V_{BE}\$, about 0.7V. It's up to the periphery to apply some arbitrary base potential \$V_B\$, and inherent negative feedback of the emitter follower arrangement maintains the condition \$V_E = V_B - 0.7V\$. It's rare that we see or allow \$V_B > V_C\$, giving rise to the naive understanding that \$V_E\$ can't rise further than \$V_C - 0.7V\$. It can, as I just explained.
In a phototransistor, that energy is derived from incident light, but there is no inherent negative feedback at work. The transistor can "saturate" from incident light alone, without the need to explicitly set base potential electrically. Consequently you find that a well-illuminated phototransistor configured as an emitter follower is quite able to produce \$V_E = V_C - V_{CE(SAT)}\$.
My understanding of the physics is rudimentary at best, but photons striking the base-collector junction produce electron-hole pairs, which are then free to migrate under the influence of the electric field within the depletion region to produce a small current, current that by KCL must pass via the emitter (assuming the base is unconnected).
Using an NPN BJT as an example, usually we explicitly evoke base-to-emitter current by connecting a source of current directly to the transistor's base terminal. With the phototransistor, however, the tiny photo-current produced within the base-collector junction effectively performs the same function. Sure, it's current that comes via the collector terminal, not the base terminal, but it's still current entering the base region and leaving via the emitter, and the transistor makes no distinction.
Within the base region, electron-hole recombination still occurs, to form what we would usually refer to as "base current" (even though in this case it is actually photo-current), and β times as many electrons enter the base-collector junction directly, to become collector current.
Saturation is the state in which collector and emitter potentials are similar, within about 0.1V or so of each other. Either the emitter has risen in potential to "meet" the collector, or collector potential has fallen. Either way, in such a state there is no longer a sufficiently strong electric field to pull electrons from the base region across the base-collector junction, and the usual relationship \$I_C = \beta I_B\$ (where in this case \$I_B\$ is photo-current) is no longer true. From a certain perspective you might say that the relationship is still true, but \$\beta\$ has fallen to zero.
Where the phototransistor is concerned, as \$V_{CE}\$ approaches zero, further increases in photo-current (by illuminating it more strongly) will have little effect on \$V_{CE}\$. In this state where \$\beta \approx 0\$, \$\Delta I_C = \beta \times \Delta I_B \approx 0\$, which is exactly the same behaviour you would expect from a regular BJT in saturation.

Could you please elaborate on how a phototransistor is saturated ?
( the last paragraph)

Is it an emitter follower?
Emitter follower. No, it is not, despite having an emitter resistor. In an emitter follower, there is an input voltage. The voltage across the emitter resistor is subtracted from this input voltage, and the difference is applied to the input (base-emitter junction) of the transistor. As a result, negative feedback comes into play.
Optocoupler circuit. Here, the light acts as a base current that induces a collector current, but there is no explicit input voltage. The current only creates a voltage drop across the emitter resistor, which is used as the output, and that is it. The fact that the resistor is connected in the emitter circuit is irrelevant here. It could just as well be connected in the collector circuit and the result would be the same.
Conceptual circuit
We can illustrate this with a conceptual circuit where we represent the transistor as a variable resistor Rvar. To monitor the current, we can represent the constant resistor R with an ammeter with the same 1 kΩ internal resistance.
Let's examine all possible combinations to verify that there is no difference.
Rvar grounded, R floating, Vcc grounded

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab

Rvar floating, R grounded, Vcc grounded

simulate this circuit

Rvar grounded, R grounded, Vcc floating

simulate this circuit

Rvar floating, R grounded, Vcc grounded

simulate this circuit

Results: Indeed, regardless of the connection method, the current is the same (5 mA); therefore, the voltage across resistor R is the same (5 V).
Also, we see that the output voltage's dependence on the resistance is the same regardless of the connection variant.
Optocircuit
Now, let's examine the typical variants of the real transistor circuit, simulating the light by directly applying a voltage Vbe to the base-emitter junction and adjusting it so that the same 5 mA current flows as before.
Common-emitter stage
First, let's connect the resistor in the collector. This schematic corresponds to the conceptual Schematic 1.1 above and resembles a common-emitter stage without negative feedback. As you can see, 701 mV input base-emitter voltage causes 5 mA collector current.

simulate this circuit
Let's also DC sweep Vbe by changing Vbe from 690 mV to 710 mV.

"Emitter follower"
Then let's move the resistor in the emitter circuit (and continue applying Vbe = 701 mV to the base-emitter junction). This schematic corresponds to the conceptual Schematic 1.2 above. The same 5mA current flows and creates the same 5 V drop across R.
So, even though the circuit resembles a common-collector stage (emitter follower), it actually continues to have the properties of a common-emitter stage.

simulate this circuit
The graph is the same as the one above.

Emitter follower
Finally, let's make a true emitter follower to see the difference. For this purpose, we disconnect the negative terminal of the input voltage source and connect it to ground.

simulate this circuit
The result is striking. The negative feedback opposes the input voltage by subtracting 5 V from it, and the same 701 mV leave as before. So, to get the same output current and voltage, we need to increase the input voltage by 5 V.
The graph is also different.

This is how we experimentally verified that your circuit is not an emitter follower.
What is saturation?
Since you are interested in the nature of the phenomenon "saturation", I will explain it to you as simply as possible using the concept of resistance.
Generally speaking, the main property of a control element (a variable resistor in a conceptual circuit and a transistor in a real circuit) is to provide resistance to the current. In its effort to increase the current more and more (at maximum light), it decreases its resistance more and more until it finally depletes (zero) it. Figuratively speaking, the saturated control device is just a "piece of wire". The voltage across it is zero, and the whole supply voltage is applied to the resistor Re.
In this context, saturation refers to a state in which a device, such as a phototransistor, can no longer increase its output current, regardless of the input signal (light). It reaches a maximum limit. This is what is called "saturation".
Here is what the circuit looks like when the transistor is saturated.

simulate this circuit

The bjt in emitter follower works in linear region, on other hand your opto-circuit works as switch.
In emitter follower the equation:
V2 = Vbe + Vout is valid.
In opto-circuit this equation cannot be written.
Btw, the emitter follower is even kind of regulator from certain point of view, where bjt takes certain ib to reach V2-0.7 at Vout.
In opto-circuit a regulation is not presented.

In emitter follower the equation:
V2 = Vbe + Vout is valid.
In opto-circuit this equation cannot be written. Could you expand?

The 0.6V potential is needed to rise above the B-E band gap.  In a similar vein, photons with an energy below 0.6eV will not register with the phototransistor.  The photons must be energetic enough to get an electron across the band gap.  When the low-current forward voltage of the LED is larger than that of the phototransistor, this will generally be the case for photons sent by the LED.
So in a way, your 0.6V is still there but it is folded into the LED forward voltage, and since LED and phototransistor are galvanically separated, it has no bearing on the minimum C-E voltage.

I am going to try to expand on the answer from Michal Podmanický. They wrote:
In emitter follower the equation:
V2 = Vbe + Vout is valid.
In opto-circuit this equation cannot be written.

The basic point is that the optocoupler LED and transistor parts are completely isolated from one another electrically (which is often the reason to use one). This means that Vb* has no direct effect on Ve or Vc. Instead the effect that the LED side has on the transistor side is solely controlled by the current through the LED.
I have made an example simulation here.


The top left circuit is the one you made, and as you can see there is 14.144mA going into the optocoupler.
The one in the top right is exactly the same, except that I have added a 50V DC offset to the LED side of the optocoupler. This means that the 2V voltage drop across the resistor-LED pair goes from 52V to 50V. But this changes nothing on the transistor side, as the current through the LED is still 14.144mA.
Finally, on the bottom I have raised the voltage across the resistor-LED pair to 20V - but I also adjusted the resistor so that the current is still 14.144mA. This means that it still performs exactly as the two other circuits on the transistor side.

(*) Talking about the base in an optocoupler does not really make sense (unless you pull it apart like in the answer from bobflux). Instead the four connectors are: Emitter, Collector, Anode, and Cathode as seen in this datasheet.
